# Function evaluation timed out

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql

I am using linq to sql in a Silverlight application and I keep getting this debug error..

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bf4055b4ee.jpg

This code runs when the application is started up without problems. When I call it the second time, I only get a few of the results. When I add a breakpoint to the WCF service I get the following error...

Could someone please tell me whats going on here so i can make some changes?

TIA

ps. Might not be the most efficient coding but I will sort all that out later :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a breakpoint to the service code the caller will throw a Timeout Exception after the timeout time has passed. Raise the timeout of your service (on the server and client side), this will allow you to debug your service code without getting exceptions.